# DateTime manipulaton in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm new in C# and I need to understand how create a DateTime object that equal the (DateTime.NOW + 1 hour).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx) a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) value that represents any arbitrary interval to a `DateTime`. There are helper methods on `TimeSpan` that help you construct such values, for example:

```
DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
```

Apart from that, since you only want the simple "+1 hour" you can also use `AddHours`:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var inOneHour = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime newTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`AddHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx) function;

```
DateTime oneHourInTheFuture = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to Nullable the DataTime object you could also do something like this

```
  DateTime? newTimeHour;
  newTimeHour = new DateTime();
  newTimeHour = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```